# jQuery Scroll animation speed

Tags: jquery, animation

I am making an info screen in jQuery and need the animation speed to be evenly through the whole animation. I am using this code:

```
$("#panel1").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#panel1")[0].scrollHeight 
}, 100000);
```

Comment: What makes you think that it is uneven?

Comment: The scrolling starts slowly, and goes faster and faster until the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is the easing to use. By default it's `swing`. You can change that to `linear`, like this:

```
$("#panel1").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $("#panel1")[0].scrollHeight 
}, 100000, 'linear');
```